# SVN do not recognise changes locally in specific directory

Tags: svn, version-control, command-line

I have a directory called `/downloads/assets/guidance/` that is in my SVN repository and holds a number of images. The images, however, are *not* in the repo and are content-managed.

I am using svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486).

I have a number of images in that directory that are showing up as unrecognised `?`, however there are so many of them that the fill the buffer in the command line and I cannot view my *actual* changes.

I am left with a ton of these (output from `svn stat`):

```
?       downloads/assets/guidance/55.jpg
?       downloads/assets/guidance/19.jpg
?       downloads/assets/guidance/38.jpg
?       downloads/assets/guidance/56.jpg
?       downloads/assets/guidance/39.jpg
?       downloads/assets/guidance/57.jpg
?       downloads/assets/guidance/58.jpg
```

How can I ignore these files/directories in my local working copy **only** without affecting the SVN repo that is shared with a number of other developers?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about the output of `svn stat`. Just use the option `-q` (`--quiet`). It will suppress all unversioned items:

```
svn stat -q downloads/assets/
```

**Updated:** You can also set the property `svn:ignore` to automatically suppress some unversioned files:

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*.jpg' download/assets
```

In this case, you can use the option `--no-ignore` to ignore svn:ignore properties, i.e. show files that would have been suppressed.

Comment: The output that I have provided is from `svn stat`, yes. I don't want to suppress __all__ unversioned items. I only want to suppress unversioned items from appearing in an `svn stat` from the `downloads/assets/` directory - is this possible?

Comment: My concern is if I apply this `propset` locally would it then be copied up to the repo the next time I commit, subsequently affecting everyone else that is working from the same repo? That is something that I _don't_ want to do. Essentially I want to affect my working copy only.

Comment: I am aware that I could do this: `svn st | grep -v downloads/assets/` to ignore everything within that directory. But it's not permanent within my working copy.